# how to connect to Hbase managed zookeeper

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I created a Hbase test ENV using Pseudo-Distributed mode, and I don't setup an independent zookeeper, I'm wondering how could I connect to zookeeper managed by hbase?  I could not find zkCli.sh in hbase installation folder.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use zkCli tool which is integrated into HBase:

```
./hbase zkcli -server host:port <cmd> <args>
```

Documentation page: https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#trouble.tools.builtin.zkcli